# Deleted administrator user. Not getting my personal data

Tags: 15.04, data-recovery, delete

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04. But I deleted the administrator user by mistake, and now I cannot get my personal files. What happened to my personal files? Are they there or are they removed from the disk? If they are there then please help me to recover them.

Comment: What do you mean by administrator user ? is it a normal user with `sudo` privelege or what ? what is your username ?

Comment: I want to add that it is normal user with sudo privilege

Comment: How did you remove the user i mean what command have you used ?

Comment: using system settings->user accounts

Comment: There should be a prompt `Do you want to keep test's files?` what did you select then ? `Delete files` or `Keep files` ?

Answer (score -5):

if you deleted your own user then your data is probably gone. You could try first to see under /home if there is a directory with your former username, or
try something like [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Look, its not my job to correct you every time but this is the second time i have to tell you this is a very poor answer..this is wholely based on assumption and agin a link to another answer..if you have any confusion or want feedback from the OP just make it a comment..i would suggest you to read [How do I write a good answer?](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) ..Good luck..